# During a while loop file read, where is the first line of stdin lost?

Tags: shell, while-loop

Assume we have a file with the numbers 1 to 5 written down line by line.
When I open a file for reading as standard input and use 'while read,' commands which can read stdin are unable to read the first line of that file.

`$ while read x; do sed ''; done<file`

> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5

It makes no difference which command you use: sed, awk, cat, etc. That problem occurs if the command is able to read from stdin.There is also no difference between the shells I use. I try the same thing in sh, bash, and zsh, and the results are identical.

It's worth noting that the loop iterates five times, once for each line. For example:

`$ while read x; do printf 'something\n'; done<file`

> something
> something
> something
> something
> something

I understand that if I want to read all lines correctly, I must specify a variable in the read command and then pass it to the command. But I'm trying to figure out what's going on here. Why does this problem occur when I do not specify input for a command directly?
Perhaps it is a side effect with no functional purpose.

I couldn't find any information about this behavior of the 'while read' statement, and neither did I find anyone who had a similar problem.

Comment: The line is going into `$x`. If you `echo "$x"; sed ''`, then you'll see it back.

Comment: Or if you want each copy of `sed` to process only the one line that `read` consumed, then `echo "$x" | sed ''` and you'll get a separate copy of `sed` per line of input.

Comment: It might be enlightening to change your test slightly and write: `seq 4 | while read x; do printf 'something\n'; sed -e 's/^/sed:/'; done`  This would show that the while loop only actually executes once.

Comment: `read` and `sed` *both* read from the standard input inherited from the loop. `printf` inherits the standard input as well, but does not *read* from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only iterates *once*.

```
while read x; do sed ''; done<file
```

...behaves as follows:

1. `file` is opened and attached to stdin
2. `read` consumes the first line of the file from stdin and puts it into `$x`
3. `sed ''` consumes *the entire rest of the file* from stdin and prints it to stdout without changes.
4. `read` sees there's no more data (because `sed` consumed it all), and the loop ends.

---

If you want `sed` to operate on only the one line that `read x` consumed, and to safeguard against other bugs, you might instead write:

```
while IFS= read -r x; do printf '%s\n' "$x" | sed ''; done <file
```

The changes:

- Using `IFS=` prevents leading or trailing whitespace from being deleted by `read`.
- Using the `-r` argument prevents backslashes from being consumed by `read`.
- Piping from `printf '%s\n' "$x"` into `sed` changes `sed`'s stdin, such that instead of containing the *rest of the file*, it only contains the one line. Thus, this ensures that `sed` is processing the line that was consumed by `read`, instead of ignoring that line and processing the entire rest of the file. (Using `printf` instead of `echo` is a correctness concern; see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) on [UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)).